# Why can you store a long into a float without typecast

Tags: java, casting, long-integer

Ok so I know float is 32 bit decimal. Double is 64 bit decimal. Long is 64 bit whole number. So why is this value: Float(32 bit) <- Long (64 bit). Obviously not java code but I'm referring to it in java. It automagically casts even though it crunches it into 32 bits and loses precision. So that means precision does not matter. However int <- double does not work unless you explicitly cast the double to an int. It is a smaller size and they are both numbers and both primitives. Is it just the general rule: Decimal Number <- Whole number regardless of bit size. It will just loop back around. Just that rule and everything works among Numbers in java? To show actual code:

```
long L = 10_000L;
float f = L;
```

Note that the question is specifically about `long` to `float` without an explicit cast, not `float` to `long`, not about explicit casting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Show your **actual** code, rather than a description of it.

Comment: In general, we are not the designers of the language, so we can't answer "why" questions about decisions made in the language's design.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: `float` has a wider range than `long`

Comment: @PeterLawrey but float is 32 bit, long is 64...

Comment: The range of float is approx -3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38. The range of a 64-bit long is -9.2e+18 to +9.2e+18.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting `long` to `float` is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2). Java allows it without error because...it's defined that way. From the link:

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - **`long` to `float` or `double`**
>
> ...
>
> **A widening primitive conversion from** `int` to `float`, or from **`long` to `float`**, or from long to double, **may result in loss of precision** - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).

*(My emphasis.)*

Why allow it without requiring an explicit cast? In general, only James Gosling and others there at the time can answer that sort of question. For the rest of us, the answer is: Because that's what the specification says.

**However**, I'll note that even though precision is lost, overall magnitude is not, which I'd wager is why it's allowed. `float` can hold **very** large values imprecisely. So for instance:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        float f = l;
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Run that and you get:

```
9223372036854775807
9.223372E18
```

9.223372e18 is 9223372000000000000. Compare:

```
9223372036854775807 - the long value
9223372000000000000 - the float value
```

This is because `float` can sacrifice precision for range of value, because it stores a base value that it raises to an exponent. From [Wikipedia's article on the IEEE-754 binary32 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (which is what Java's `float` is):

> ...an IEEE 754 32-bit base-2 floating-point variable has a maximum value of (2 − 2<sup>−23</sup>) × 2<sup>127</sup> ≈ 3.402823 × 10<sup>38</sup>...

3.402823 × 10<sup>38</sup> is:

```
340,282,300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

...**but** the highest integer it can store such that you can add 1 and not lose precision is just 2<sup>24</sup>-1 (16,777,215). It can store 16,777,216, but not 16,777,217. So 16,777,216 + 1 is still 16,777,216:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 16_777_216f;
        System.out.println(String.format("%8.0f", f));     // 16777216
        System.out.println(String.format("%8.0f", f + 1)); // 16777216 (still)
    }
}
```

That's because it's now storing the base value divided by 2 with an exponent of 2, so it can't store odd numbers anymore. It gets worse the higher you get, being able to only store multiples of 4, then of 8, then of 16, etc.

Contrast with the maxiumum value of a `long`, which is 2<sup>63</sup>-1, which is "only":

```
9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

But unlike `float`, it can represent each and every one of those integers precisely.

Comment: But widening would mean getting bigger... 64 bit to 32 bit is getting smaller.

Comment: @T.JCrowder Thank you so much. Excellent clarification. I was sooo confused.

Comment: @gmanrocks - Yup, but the spec allows it, I believe because although the resulting `float` may well have a different number, it will be of the same magnitude. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: So it loses precision but it remembers the number of digits?

Comment: @gmanrocks - The magnitude, yes.

Answer (score -3):

There is something like implicit typecasting. Javajava casts it automatically if you will not lose information. From float to long you could lose all behind the floating point so there will be no implicit cast because normally you do not want to lose this information.

Comment: You may well lose information going from `long` to `float`. That's the point of the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. I understand that in general, it is not particularly useful. I'm more getting at why this is allowed... I've always thought getting smaller requires explicit casting.